# Перенаправление трафика с VpnService на Android. SocketTimeoutException после прочтения ответа

Tags: android, сокет, vpn

Я сперва задал вопрос на [4pda](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=184237&view=findpost&p=39939559), но он там уже ушел в историю.

Пишу приложение, функциональность которого похожа на [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java): весь трафик пишется в TUN-устройство и оттуда перенаправляется по местам назначения.

Исходник: https://bitbucket.org/MaksimDmitriev/norootfirewall/src/006f7c33cd1cd4055f372ed3a88664fe2a4be3dd/src/com/norootfw/NoRootFwService.java?at=unix

Отличие от ToyVpn в том, что трафик не посылается на удаленный VPN, а обрабатывается локально в приложении: из TUN считывается IP-пакет, делается защищенный сокет, делается запрос, получается ответ, ответ пишется в TUN.

Вот так я инициализирую TUN-устройство:

```
mInterface = new Builder().setSession(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .addAddress("10.0.2.1", 24)
                .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 1)
                .addRoute("128.0.0.0", 1)
                .establish();
```

Далее инициализирую файловые дескрипторы для работы с TUN-устройством:

```
in = new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
out = new FileOutputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
```

Создаваемому устройству TUN назначаются маршруты 0.0.0.0 и 128.0.0.0 с длиной префикса, равной единице. Таким образом, данный маршрут оказывается более предпочтительным по сравнению с маршрутом по умолчанию, IP-адрес которого 0.0.0.0, а длина префикса равна нулю.
Хотя с единственным маршрутом 0.0.0.0 и длиной префикса 0 ошибка такая же (см. ниже).

Далее приведу пример UDP-запроса.

1). Считали пакет третьего уровня модели OSI из TUN-устройства (см. структуру пакета [на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4))

```
05-06 00:46:52.749: D/UDPChecksum(31077): Sent == [69, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 64, 0, 64, 17, 108, 91, 10, 0, 2, 1, -64, -88, 1, -59, -53, 1, -50, -87, 0, 16, 89, -114, 85, 68, 80, 95, 68, 65, 84, 65]
```

Для примера: первое число 69. В двоичной системе 69 = 0100 0101, что означает версию IP 4 (старшие 4 бита) размер заголовка 20 (младшие 4). Смысл остальным числам из приведенного выше массива байт можно придать, рассмотрев структуру IP-пакета.

2). Сделали защищенный сокет, отцепили от пакета, что выше, данные 7 уровня, отправили по месту назначения, получили ответ.

3). Переставили местами IP-адрес источника и назначения, посчитали контрольную сумму IP-заголовка

4). Считаем контрольную сумму для псевозаголовка UDP:

```
05-06 00:46:52.889: D/UDPChecksum(31077): mIpv4PseudoHeader == [-64, -88, 1, -59, 10, 0, 2, 1, 0, 17, 0, 14]
```

Ставим значения контрольных сумм для IP-заголовка и UDP на нужные индексы.
Эти данные записываем в TUN-устройство:

```
05-06 00:46:52.889: D/UDPChecksum(31077): To TUN == [69, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 64, 0, 64, 17, 108, 93, -64, -88, 1, -59, 10, 0, 2, 1, -50, -87, -53, 1, 0, 14, -105, -72, 85, 68, 80, 95, 79, 75]
```

Вот так:

```
out.write(toTun);
```

Ответ до места назначения доходит. Массив для получения ответа заполняется.

```
        byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[RESPONSE_SIZE];
        try {
            mDatagramSocket.send(mDatagramPacket);
            final DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(responseBuffer, responseBuffer.length);
            mDatagramSocket.receive(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("NoRootFwService", "error: " + Arrays.toString(responseBuffer)); // I can see the correct response here.
            logException(e);
        }
```

Но сокет выбрасывает исключение по таймауту:

```
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:551)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:161)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:169)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:250)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at socket.client.MainActivity$UdpThread.run(MainActivity.java:195)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
05-05 23:46:58.389: E/CLIENT(20553):    ... 4 more
```

Без включения VpnService данные уходят и приходят нормально.

На StackOverflow не так-то много по данной теме обсуждается, но и имеющееся пока не помогло:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820461/1065835
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/20237743/1065835
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30064823/1065835 (мой вопрос в
  англоязычном SO)

Comment: https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/188 вот это похоже на решение проблемы ('setEndCallback watches for notifications that there is no longer any data being sent by the stream, or errors')

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, Это врядли. Поскольку они рекомендуют что-то для либы, построенной на сокетах. У меня сокет без моего TUN'а все отлично принимает. С моим TUN'ом вываливается.

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, к тому же я не могу заставить все клиентские приложения делать с сокетами то, что делают создатели либы. Наоборот я должен обеспечить, чтобы моя прослойка работала со всеми сокетами в клиентском коде

Comment: А вот строки 145-147 в NoRootFwService, так точно правильно делать? Это же длины хедеров старого пакета

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, я Wireshark'ом смотрел без моего VPN. У IP-заголовка размер такой же. У UDP он всегда 8.

Comment: слушай, по-идее же ты можешь делать с сокетами всё что хочешь, пока ты передаёшь пакеты туда и обратно. Значит, сокет можно и нужно закрывать (это же UDP, он не знает, что с той стороны данные больше не передаются)

Comment: собрал у себя, запустил, SocketTimeout не падаетXD. Пакеты нормально идут через NoRootFwService

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, а можешь пример с приложения с сокетами дать? На каком устройстве тестил? Какой коммит моего файрвола взял?

Comment: тестил на Huawei Honor 4C (android 4.4.2). Приложение простое совсем - http://ideone.com/WpuQsk и сервак (не на устройстве, а на другом компьютере в моей подсети) - http://ideone.com/l5gytR. Твой файрволл - https://bitbucket.org/MaksimDmitriev/norootfirewall/raw/006f7c33cd1cd4055f372ed3a88664fe2a4be3dd/src/com/norootfw/NoRootFwService.java

Comment: Коммит [006f7c3](https://bitbucket.org/MaksimDmitriev/norootfirewall/commits/006f7c33cd1cd4055f372ed3a88664fe2a4be3dd?at=unix)

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, уверен, что трафик идет через TUN? У меня просто на CyanogenMod на Samsung вообще все мимо файрвола идет.

Comment: У меня там не CM, трафик через файрвол идёт (я и логи добавлял и брейкпоинт там ставил)

Comment: @SemyonDanilov, ну что ж. Тогда можешь написать ответ? Здесь и на англоязычном SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/30064823/1065835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я считал контрольную сумму от неверного псевдозаголовка IPv4. Я не включал сами данные. Внимательно посмотрите на псевдозаголовок в моем вопросе. Он слишком короткий, и данных в нем нет.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]